# Display binary tree using JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

One of my DB tables contains data that suits well to be rendered as a binary tree.

Now my requirement is to display the data read from the DB in the format of a Binary tree. The tree can go down to any level also each node of the tree should act as a hyper link so the displayed tree should not be an image.

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve that using JSP (I mean my end output should be HTML) as my app is a J2EE application. 
Applet is ruled out here as the nodes should act as hyper links.

If there are any tools/frameworks for this, pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a javascript based graph rendering engine to render this. You could then attach urls to each node and make them navigable. Try http://bluff.jcoglan.com/api.html for graphs. You can lookup js graphing libraries and you will find many. It may also be a good time to get some  based libraries and do it natively in HTML :)

Comment: Try this thread in StackOverflow for more answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript