# Google Wonder Wheel API or js widget

Tags: javascript, html, api

Do you know a Google API or a jQuery JavaScript plugin to visualize data like the "Wonder Wheel"? I'd like to use this widget with my data.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org). See the [Tree Animation example](http://thejit.org/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example1.html) for a Wonder Wheel-like implementation.

You will find an interesting discussion related to this question here: [Graph visualization code in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

Buon lavoro,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

the closest jQuery plugin would probably be the "radmenu" plugin - http://www.tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin

more specifically, see: http://www.tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin#code_example_4

though the nesting involved in the wonder wheel is more complex that what the plugin is intended for, it can still be extended to work like the wonder wheel since it will dish out the necessary 'results' without your having to do the math