# (interactive) graph as in graph theory on a web page?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph visualization code in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

I have to integrate a graph with nodes and edges on a web page. Ideally, i would like to be able to interact with it (like moving the nodes around).

Actually, i'm beginning by representing trees, so i would appreciate to be able to collapse subtrees.

How can I do that ? I was considering google-visualization api but i wasn't able to find the kind of visualization i'm looking for (org chart doesn't allow to have multiple fathers, if i understood well)

I've got no idea of the kind of technology so my tagging may not be really accurate :-).

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two other options are:

- [Prefuse Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) which is in flash
- [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) (JIT)

Comment: I personally think JIT looks like a great library. Whilst i'm not if sure you can drag nodes, the layouts and animated transitions look great. I also like the fact that you can load data on demand. Hope it helps.

Comment: thejit is really what i was looking for, that's pretty easy, and rendering many nodes is not that slow.

Answer (score 3):

[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) may be of interest to you. Particularly [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html).

Comment: that's really nice. :-). Do you know if you can represent many nodes (~2000) ?

Comment: No idea. But you might think about whether you can fit 2000 nodes into a display window. Maybe it makes more sense to hide, rescale or otherwise only show nodes of interest, on demand.

Comment: you're right, that's why i wanted to collapse part of the graph...

Answer (score 1):

http://processingjs.org/ might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for [SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) (all 'newer' browsers implement it more or less; older via plugins: e.g. IE6).

If you want to make it interactive javascript manipulation should be doable.