# javascript framework for relationship visualization

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, javascript-framework, tree-nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph visualization code in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

I need to create a dynamic visualization for nodes and their relationships in Javascript.  What's the best framework to use?  This is what I've briefly reviewed so far:

- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) - it's Flash and hasn't been updated in almost 2 years.
- [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) - interaction seems a little slow, maybe that's on purpose in the demos
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) - documentation looks great, doesn't work in IE at all (can I get it to work with some kind of IE SVG adapter?)

Are these the best for displaying nodes in a graph and interacting with them in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Infovis seems really great compared to the framework I've seen before, here are some I've found when I was looking for such a framework (a long time ago):

- [jsgraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpgraph/) - if you're looking for "simplicity"
- [binviz](http://binviz.sourceforge.net/) - for visualisation and interaction of graph

Comment: your jsgraph link is to a php library, I think you meant http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/.  Looks interesting in its simplicity, but I'd rather have a more complete graph framework.

Comment: Yep, you're right! :-) I have googled to quickly the js-graph-it resource ...

Answer (score 1):

InfoVis is probably your best bet, for IE compatibility look for solutions built on [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

**edit** [Here's something](http://jasonrowe.com/2010/09/25/force-directed-graph-with-raphael/) you could build on, based on Google:"raphael force directed graph".

Comment: Based purely on your comment ProtoVis doesn't work on IE. I haven't heard of any IE-SVG adapter, not to say one doesn't exist. Not sure InfoVis does either, couldn't see a statement either way on the website. I know it uses Canvas though so I think that means IE9.