# How to create a multiple linked & directed graph with javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, directed-graph, flare

This is my problem: For a school project we are trying to create a directed graph and make it fit in a typical html website. We figured out it had to be written in javascript, because a java applet isn´t an option. So this is how it should look like: [image](https://8813532934917609886-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/interruptiegraaf/home/graaf.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cqShoOPHxUTW8Wd7DRAwyAMfHzjDDAWxv78BbCG4DsrNaeb66jmPQr9CFFXnEQIwV4o8q0a5jD8wLFCjfFRWx_M1mfGfyLys1pX-s6YVo-1joVzsVnWGUKdyUsKKzkz7B25M6D5Jl2ZfYR-x8Dfl4KIwWoIKS0l4jAZdv0L1eJvsyxINVVmsJXJv79MnieavtzKv4V9S8-bQUDb23AMtry_8HSXcQ%3D%3D&attredirects=0).

The data visualised in the graph will be gathered from some xml files.
We took a look at flare and some other packages, but real thing is making a two-way link between the nodes (where the thickness of the arrow represents importance) in our graph. Making the whole thing moveable is also required. 
Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at jsPlumb - a not featurerich but easy customizable jQuery Plugin for directed graphs

http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/jquery/demo.html