# Flexible graph visualization framework for Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization

I'm looking for a flexible graph visualisation framework for Javascript similar to the flex component [SpringGraph](http://mark-shepherd.com/blog/springgraph-flex-component/). I need to be able to represent nodes to be different visual components e.g. be a window, image etc. be able to name edges etc. Any recommendations?

Comment: It would be critical to know your browser target requirements - if you need IE6-8 support it's a totally different answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph visualization code in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

Some good options are:

- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) (Succeeded by [d3.js](http://d3js.org/))
- [JavaScript Infovis toolkit](http://thejit.org/)
- [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/)

Answer (score 3):

[d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), the successor of Protovis, is nice as well.

Answer (score 2):

We produce [mxGraph](https://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html), it is designed to provide maximum visualization flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Commercially licensed library [KeyLines](http://key-lines.com) is a good alternative (disclaimer: I'm an author), if the project is for business. If for home/academic projects, or just to learn a great framework, I'd vote up D3 too, it rocks!  For more abstract/graphical stuff you could check out paper.js too.

Comment: Edited to add disclaimer - knuckles rapped! - and added paper.js as a possible alternative for balance too..

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [this](http://flare.prefuse.org/) site.