# Family tree with spouses algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm tasked with creating a family tree drawing application. I ported the code for n-ary tree drawing from http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/ and while it's fine for drawing a tree where every node has only one parent but i need a way to let nodes have two parents and also allow parents to have other spouses and children with those spouses. I can't find any algorithms for family trees that would also include spouses.

I'm programming this in objective-c and i need it to look like a top down tree and not a force directed graph or circular tree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/PHP Family Tree Builder with Multiple Parents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639142/javascript-php-family-tree-builder-with-multiple-parents)

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Why would programming language have anything to say here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There may be third party libraries in one language that aren't available in another.

Comment: Very very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163683/cycles-in-family-tree-software

Comment: @biziclop But then the question falls prey to recommendation for a library, which is off-topic.

Comment: What it comes down to is that Family Trees are not mathematical/logical trees.  Period.  Use a "mathematical graph" library, or write your own (not a graphics or graphing library)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, it doesn't.

Comment: This type of conceptual question (basically software requirements) would be a better fit on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) than SO.