# What's the fastest, pure Javascript, Graph visualization toolkit?

Tags: javascript, html, graph, visualization

This question is about toolkits which draw graphs (those things composed of vertices and edges), not generic plots.

The tool must be able to get a set of vertices and edges, calculate their layout, and display them either using the canvas tag, or SVG, that is be compatible with HTML5.

Flash-based tools and java applets are out.

to serve as unified benchmark, please measure and report how long it takes for the toolkit to layout and draw a Barabasi-Albert graph with 100 vertices and 5 edges per node.

This python lybrary shows how to generate it and exports it to many formats:

http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#graph-generators-and-graph-operations

Please indicate browser and CPU.

Comment: The question is a copy of http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript, aside from the poster asking which one is fastest. However, none of the answers deal with the speed question, making it a clone thread of a poll that's been closed and locked. Also, the benchmark suggested isn't a standard and there's nothing factual to suggest it's a good benchmark to use. The results would vary wildly by browser and browser versions used.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) is awesome and i have not seen a competitor to it.

Comment: Infovis does seem pretty performant, from the demos I've seen. I think i'll be adopting it.

Answer (score 16):

Data Driven Documents (d3.js) http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ is quite good in my experience as it scales up quite good; can easily handle 100 nodes (or more?) without any stall

Answer (score 8):

We produce [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html), it is a entirely client-side graph visualization library. We optimise precisely for this one domain, not just general drawing, so we've quite a speed advantages that part-time projects in this field won't be able to implement.

Comment: You appear to be a diagramming library, not a network graph library, from the look of your website.

Answer (score 7):

[Canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) is a pure Javascript renderer of the excellent [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  Graphviz is used on the server to generate the layout, but rather than generating an image it can be rendered with canviz on the client instead.

[There is a demo](http://www.ryandesign.com/canviz/).