# Displaying a very large graph using JIT

Tags: javascript, graph, jit

I want to show a unidirectional graph to the user in a webpage. I am currently using [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit (JIT)](http://thejit.org/) as the visulization library.

The problem is that the graph has many nodes and edges and the browser cannot keep up with all of it and slows down. Here is a screenshot of part a graph:

[image: Screenshot of the graph with many nodes]

I think the problem will be solved if the graph is shown partially. So when user clicks on a node that node and nodes around it should be expanded (shown) and some far nodes should be collapsed (hidden) to prevent performance issues.

Based on this idea I I've written a simple code that expands a node and puts it in center when a user clicks on it and collapse previous centered node. It is not a very efficient and wise way for showing nodes, anyway it doesn't work. It just collapses all the nodes and fails to expand the current clicked node.

Here is the code:

```
onClick: function(node,eventInfo,e) {
    if(node==false) 
    {
        return;
    }

    if(rgraph.previousexpand!=false)
    {
        if(rgraph.previousexpand.id!=node.id)
        {
            rgraph.op.contract(rgraph.previousexpand, {  
                type: 'animate',  
                duration: 3000,  
                hideLabels: true,  
                transition: $jit.Trans.Quart.easeOut  
            });                 
        }
    }

    rgraph.previousexpand = node;
    rgraph.op.expand(rgraph.previousexpand, {  
       type: 'animate',  
       duration: 3000,  
       hideLabels: true,  
       transition: $jit.Trans.Quart.easeOut  
    }); 

    rgraph.onClick(node.id);
}
```

And in initialization:

```
rgraph.previousexpand=false;
```

First, do you know any better way for showing a very large graph? Is there any other solution in JIT or maybe other library that show graph in this way?

Second, what i am missing in the code?

Comment: It seems like a dead, left out question, but in case you are still seeking for answer, please provide a Jsfiddle link or something refigh! [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237) however is a good reference for a bunch of JS libraries for graph visualization.