# BPMB visualization

Tags: workflow, visualization, bpmn

We need to visualize BP (business process) into BPMN, but NOT by hands using modeler. We need to do it automatically in crm-web-based system written on PHP. I have input data (etc. array, xml, not care...(but not BPEL)), then I need to process it into nice BPMN graph (using SVG).
We have first nice-looking realization of it. We use matrix to draw: several times goes through matrix and optimize graph each time, no no, it working fast, but it not agile, hard to rebuilt, upgrade, add new features... We made this algorithm by ourselves (I mean we didn't find it in google or books). Problem is that we couldn't find any algorithms in the internet. I suppose we don't know correct keywords to do it. Every try returned us to BPEL vis. from BPMN, "Data flow vis." returned modelers...
Please help us to find some algorithms, or give correct keywords to find out information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you're probably looking for "graph layout algorithms".  The only library I'm aware of that can (I think) generate BPMN directly is the yFiles library from [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html).  It's not free. They do however offer a free application using the library that does auto-layout.  Perhaps you could do some prototyping with that.

If that's not applicable, there are several other options.  I'm not aware any of these can generate BPMN symbols directly; you'd have to construct the symbols.  However all will auto-layout graphs according to various algorithms.  Also all open source/free.

- [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/).  Written in C.  Quite old now but well used, stable and scalable.
- [tulip](http://tulip.labri.fr/TulipDrupal/).  Newer than graphviz.  Haven't used it but heard good things about flexibility and scalability.
- see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript) for javascript based options.

There are many more, just google for graph layout algorithms / libraries.
hth.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: There is also a way to **plot BPMN using R**, see https://github.com/bergant/bpmn