# Draw a binary tree

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm looking for a js lib which allows the user to draw a binary tree : add/remove a leaf, add/remove a parent node, etc.

I've found many libs but most of them are made for data visualization only (eg: d3), not drawing from the browser.

Does this even exist ?

Thanks!

Comment: I know I'm a bad case of NIH syndrome, but wouldn't that trivial enough and fun enough to write it yourself? Also do you mean interactively creating a tree or drawing a tree given the definition (e.g. just computing a decent tree geometry for visualization)?

Comment: I meant the former : interactively creating a tree (generate a node, click on a button, generate a leaf, click, append a leaf to the leaf, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at existing stuff to draw graphs (a tree is a graph):

[Pure JavaScript Graphviz equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344318/pure-javascript-graphviz-equivalent)

You may also write it yourself by drawing to a HTML canvas for example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_graphics_with_canvas

Comment: Thanks :) I preferred to say `tree` because `graph` may sound like `charts` for some people. I know how to draw in a canvas, I'd just prefer to know if a solution already existed for that. No need to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: That tree model js thing looks fine :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. It seems like it's a nodejs package, not a client side lib :(

Comment: As stated above, tree-model is "just" a data structure manipulation lib, not a visualization tool. I'll give http://www.jointjs.com/ a try or do it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

[Tree-model-js](http://jnuno.com/tree-model-js/) has animated example on main page by svg. You can copy and use it.

Comment: Mmh. Yeah, the visualization used here is home made using d3. The tree-model lib only allows data structure manipulation, not its visualization. I guess I'll do that by myself or use something like http://www.jointjs.com/