# Dynamic Tree Generation using javascript

Tags: javascript, tree

I have a tree structure like the following:

```
{
    "7": ["3", "8"],
    "3": ["2", "4", "1"],
    "4": ["5", "6"],
    "8": ["12", "13"]
}
```

This dictionary simply means that the root node of the tree is 7(as it is not a child of any other node) which has two children 3 and 8 while 3 has three children(2, 4, 1) and 8 has two children(12, 13). 3 has a child 4 which has two children(5,6).

My problem is that I need a dynamic tree generator as I will have different tree(And they will not be binary tree!) structure every time I shall run the code. My code is in python and I want show the tree in web.

Is there any **javascript** library which I can use to draw this tree?

Comment: asking for a library is ot.

Comment: There are any number of them; I'd just start by looking. Although if you want to draw pathological trees like this one, where nodes don't exist,  you may run into troubles.

Comment: @DaveNewton, the tree should be a valid one, I can assure that. :)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344318/pure-javascript-graphviz-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys of the object and build a new temporary object with all relations. Then delete from the root array all keys with predecessor.

Return a new object with the root key and all childrens.

```js
var data = { 7: ["3", "8"], 3: ["2", "4", "1"], 4: ["5", "6"], 8: ["12", "13"] },
    tree = function (object) {
        var root = Object.keys(data),
            o = Object.create(null),
            r = Object.create(null);

        root.slice().forEach(function (k) {
            o[k] = o[k] || {};
            data[k].forEach(function (a) {
                var p = root.indexOf(a);
                if (p !== -1) {
                    root.splice(p, 1);
                }
                o[a] = o[a] || {};
                o[k][a] = o[a];
            });
        });
        r[root] = o[root];
        return r;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```