# Web graphics framework to draw network graphs

Tags: javascript, html, graphics

Is there some sort of Javascript or webGL framework that would make creating a network graph (such as on [github](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/network)) easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael is pretty sweet: http://raphaeljs.com/ and has good browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

- http://sigmajs.org/

Thought it is only network oriented not like for example http://d3js.org/

Also see

- [Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

There are lots I guess.