# Javascript graph visualization library

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph visualization code in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

I have to create a web-application to display graphs (Nodes connected by edges).
I'd like to be able to control the color of edges as well as they labels (It would be better to have them displayed at mouse over).

I'd also like to attach some information to the nodes to show at mouse over.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like your looking for something like http://arborjs.org/ ?

Comment: Arborjs hasn't been maintained since 2012. Please don't recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

d3 (data-driven documents) is a library for creating visualizations that has been gaining traction.

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

It's a little like JQuery in that, rather than focusing on giving you ready-to-use charting "widgets", it makes it far easier to create any visualization. That said, it makes it easy to create various charts and visualizations and there are a number of examples, most with very little code.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).

It's compatible with IE6, it's able to create stunning graphics with ease and support various hover effects.

Also [Dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/) has some nice features. Check [this example](http://www.graphdracula.net/showcase/), you can connect nodes, add labels and have hover effects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a new web application, and need to get it up and running really fast, I suggest looking at [ADF DVT](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/ps1/dvt_graph/gant_chart_pivot_table.htm). It has a lot of visualizations. However, it abstracts JavaScript from you and you will need to learn the ADF Rich client framework.

EDIT
and it does [line graphs](http://blogs.oracle.com/adffun/entry/using_oracle_adf_data_visualization_tools_dvt_line_graphs_to_display_weather_information) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) - it can do all you are asking for. There are lots of [examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) with documented js - these are also available in the [download](http://code.google.com/p/flot/downloads/list).

Answer (score 0):

In a commercial scenario the [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) library seems like a perfect match for that task.

There are over a hundred of nice online demos available (HTML5 capable browser required), that show what can be done using that library: [yFiles for HTML Demos](https://live.yworks.com/)

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that produces that library, but I do not represent my employer on SO.</sup>