# How to create the tree graphs of Mind42.com?

Tags: java, ruby, graph, jruby, mindmapping

What graphics libraries exist, if any, for programming tree graphs like that of Mind42.com?  Ruby is preferred but Java could work also via calls via JRuby.

Here's a screen-cap for convenience: http://i43.tinypic.com/9levs1.jpg

Comment: My answer is for JavaScript because that's how that software is created. If you want to code only in Java or Ruby then all you can do is create a static image, you won't have this interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The graph editor [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) can make very similar things, so I assume it's possible to use the [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html) library (Java, .NET, Flash) it's based on to create such trees.

Answer (score 1):

[This is the main thread for JavaScript Visualization Libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)