# Create a Data Visualization with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, visualization

Have anyone ever heard of or has and idea of how to create a "Swarm" or "Nodal System" data visualization with JQuery and HTML5?

I've got a site with lot's of users.  The user's have relationships to each other.  Some are linked to more than one.  I want to show a bunch of avatars with lines coming from each one connecting them to other avatars.

The idea is that users can look at the "Swarm" and understand who is connected to whom.

Here's a page with some samples of what I'm looking for:
[Data Visualization Examples](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/06/50-great-examples-of-data-visualization/)

Comment: That page you linked to has several examples, none of which alike.  Which did you want?

Comment: @Brad: the page has one titled "Swarm" my vote is to assume that one until corrected otherwise...

Comment: @Cpfohl, Ah, I see it now, thanks!  It's too bad http://labs.digg.com/swarm/ is down... perhaps it is reusable as is?  Are you able to access that site?

Comment: @Brad: not a problem.  Hope I didn't sound snarky, it wasn't meant to be, but looking back it it it might have sounded so...

Comment: sorry guys, I should have mentioned an example - http://arianna.libero.it/graph/search/abin/graphnews?lemma=APPLE,

Answer (score 2):

I think tou should check out D3 a javascript awesome library for Data Visualization.

Here's the link to a Nodal System
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html

Hope could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

**Hypertree**
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Hypertree/example1.html
[image]

**Force Directed**
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html
[image]

**Rgraph**
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example1.html
[image]

**Also check**
This answer with lots of links https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/2385