# How to make simple graphs in python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I would like to make simple graphs for my web page in python/django, but I do not know, which library (and how) to use.

I DO NOT WANT CHARTS, I SEEK A WAY TO CREATE IMAGE FROM PRIMITIVES LIKE RECTANGLES.

Each such graph is probabely generated and used only one time, as next time the values would differ.

I can simply compute the positions of all rectangles, lines or texts in it, so I would like something lightweight to just create pictre from that, which I would return as img/png (or so) mime style
like <img src="http://my.web.www/my/page/graph" > where the parameters to show would be decidied by session and database.

I can compute all the sizes beforehand, so I would like something simple like

```
img=Image(PNG,598,89) # style, x, y
img.add_text('1.3.', 10,10)
img.add_rectagle(20,10, 70,20, CYAN, BLACK)
....
return img.render()
```

Can you direct me, how to do it?

Thanks beforehand

[image: graph]

---

[navit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6369873/navit) nailed it :)

```
# from django.utils.httpwrappers import HttpResponse
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import os,sys
im = Image.new('RGB',(598,89),'white')

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle((0,0,im.size[0]-1,im.size[1]-1), outline='blue')
draw.rectangle((25,10,590,20), fill='white', outline='black')
draw.rectangle((25,10,70,20), fill='rgb(255,0,0)', outline='black')
draw.rectangle((70,10,90,20), fill='green', outline='black')
draw.text((1,10),'1.3.',fill='black')
del draw

# write to stdout
im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")

# draw.flush()
# response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
# image.save(response, "PNG")
# return response
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want static chart (like an image) or dynamic chart. Either way this is a duplicated question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840255/djhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascriptango-and-interactive-graph-network-visualization and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript

Comment: I want to generate image in python (and transfer it  via http to browser, where it is displayed as any other "normal image")

Comment: My poblem is just how to construct one-time image in python. I do not want to use javascript/jquery/anything else on client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check Pillow out. Here is a sample how it works:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open("lena.pgm")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line((0, 0) + im.size, fill=128)
draw.line((0, im.size[1], im.size[0], 0), fill=128)
del draw

# write to stdout
im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")
```

Serving a file from Pillow to your client should be straightforward. Let me know if you have a question.

edit: found [these](https://github.com/daviddoria/Examples/tree/master/Python/PIL) examples to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I looked some of them, but it seems, that all do CHARTS, (as you supply data, chart magiccally appears), not IMAGES (you draw rectangles, lines, text on some canvas and get the result as a (static) image)

Comment: Thank you, exactly, what I needed. also here is simple example how to fill in django :) http://effbot.org/zone/django-pil.htm

Comment: Great ! have fun.

Comment: Included your example (customized) to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

http://matplotlib.org/ permits to generate plenty of great graphs. You should be able to save it as an image and integrate it to your webpage

Comment: I do not want to create permanent images, same them and then present them, I just want to combine some rectagles in memory and send it as image to user, then forgot it, as it never be generated the same again.

Answer (score 0):

What about [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/)? Never used in a project, but by reading the examples it seems very powerful and easy to use. It has a  [static image export](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/) (as most graphic libraries probably have).