# Editable Interactive Network Graph in Python

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

Is there any charting facility in Python that lets you edit a network graph on the fly?

To be specific, I built a network graph using bokeh, and when I scroll over a point in the graph, a small info snapshot about the data point pops up. I wonder if it is possible to edit those info on the fly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and interactive graph/network visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840255/django-and-interactive-graph-network-visualization)