# jQuery Tree Structure

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am looking for a jQuery Based tree Structure plugin for the following.

It should take three level image indicator.

1. Empty Circle - to tell there are no child elements.
2. Plus Circle - to indicate it contains child elements
3. Minus circle - to indicate collapse

[image]

Comment: You probably wanna look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript - it lists a whole list of jquery based visualization plugins that you could check out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe JSTree is something for you? http://www.jstree.com/

With JSTree you can set the icons of the treeitems yourself.

Comment: i looked into it. its a little way too complex script :(

Comment: Why is it too complex? You are looking for a JQuery tree component right? It should fold, and unfold, or not?