# JavaScript libraries that connects two Raphael objects in flowchart connectors style?

Tags: raphael

I am searching for a js lib that works on Raphael object. Means that conects multiple Raphael objects in flowchart connectors style. I works with jsplumb but is dosent work with Raphael object. So plz me know if anyone know about such js lib.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- [Dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/) is quite good, though not very active anymore.
- Raphaël offers its own extension, called *graffle*, made for this purpose. You can play around with [the demo](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html).

See also [this answer on a similar post, by the author of Dracula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript/2366237#2366237), listing many alternatives.