# Need advice on implementation possibilities (Web based)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm doing a little hobby project where I want to visualize a football league table in a rather new way. Problem is I don't know how to quite do it and thats where you brilliant guys come in.

Say that I would like to do something like this

[image]

Where each element in the list should be clickable, and it should much like behave as [Gephi does](https://gephi.org/)  Like when I hover a team all the links that that team is connected to is lightened up.

[image]

Now to my question, how would you recommend to implement this? Any software, any complete frameworks that I can use to achieve this? I am currently using Jquery for the drop down menu.

And most importanly of all, it should be a web based sollution so using html jquery, css etc (I.E not use gephi and doing a java applet, that is a final alternative)

Sorry if this is the wrong community for posting these kinds of questions, but since its a technical question in a sense I thought that it would fit here =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at a few different Javascript graphing libraries. There's a good discussion at [Graph visualization code in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript) Especially the following libraries:

- [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) ([demos](http://sigmajs.org/examples.html))
- [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/)
- [D3](http://d3js.org/) ([mouse-over example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/))
- [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) (see also [Dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/))
- [The JIT](http://philogb.github.com/jit/) ([demos](http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html))

Answer (score 0):

Lets see... Make the whole thing an image. Cut out each image that will light up. Make it a sprite with its light up counterpart. Position each sprite via absolute position where you want it. The hover part may be an issue. In order to do it in css each image the team is associated with need to be nested in the parent hovered image. It's possible. So you say something like div#team-map b#top-level:hover b#another {...}