# Javascript plugin framework for connecting drag and drop pictures using straight lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I would like to know what is the best javascript plugin / framework to connect multiple pictures using straight lines.

The pictures need to support drag and drop functionality and click functionality. 
I would prefer if the solution involves the jQuery framework.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Arbor.js looks like a good solution.

For a list of various solutions:

[Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)