# JavaScript library for dynamic network visualization?

Tags: javascript, visualization, graph-visualization

What is a good JavaScript library for the visualization of time-evolving/dynamic graphs/networks?

My data is in the form of `source -> destination at time` triples like the following

```
A -> B at 100
B -> C at 101
A -> D at 104
C -> D at 105
...
```

On the screen I would like to see an animation of points connected by edges with edges flickering on and off as time evolves.

I'm also happy to contribute to an open source library that is almost there.

Clarifications:

- By graph I mean a set of nodes connected by a set of edges, not a plot
- This question is related to (but distinct from) the following question: [Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)

Comment: Take a look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) there are some nice [examples](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) of people drawing networks and graphs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've worked with [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/), which is an open source library exactly for the purpose of drawing network graphs. It's Canvas based, so faster than SVG especially for large networks, but dynamic manipulation of nodes/edges is not as straightforward. One nice feature is you can render Gexf files, created with Gephi or other tools, with very little effort.

Comment: How much work would it take to make dynamic manipulation of nodes/edges more straightforward?  I'm willing to contribute if it's close.

Comment: This is hard to answer, you can take a look at the [public API here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/core/sigmapublic.js), maybe it already offeers what you need.

Comment: I was able to build fairly high-speed graph visualizations with sigmajs once I exposed the drawEdge method to the public API.

Answer (score 8):

[Vis.js](http://visjs.org/), a browser based visualization library, is another option for you. Also, their [public repo](https://github.com/almende/vis/) is active.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Comment: Vis.js can do arrows and edge labels, so it's perfect for directed weighted graphs in javascript

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at d3.js: "D3.js is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data"  http://d3js.org/

Here's an example of drawing a graph from a dataset: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

Here's an example that shows how to dynamically update data.  You could stream it from a server or simulate it by stepping through the data entirely on the client side: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Comment: For additional reference, I built several graphs in d3js. http://vida.io/documents/SyT7DREdQmGSpsBkK (graph with distance) and http://vida.io/documents/fGzpzjP98Bs2ShMHW (static graph)

Comment: D3.js GEXF loader: [https://github.com/emeeks/gexfd3](https://github.com/emeeks/gexfd3).  Examples: [http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks](http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks). (Search page for "gexf".)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example by [ZoomCharts](https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/examples/data-sources/add-data-incrementally.html):

[image]]

Seems this is exactly what you are looking for.

---

Disclosure: I am co-owner and core developer in ZoomCharts.com