# What tools/framework/API(and the like) that let a user create a flowchart dynamically

Tags: api, flowchart

I want to create a web-based flowchart to source code translator.

My problem is I don't know what specific flowchart making tools/framework/API to let the user create dynamically a flowchart using basic flow-charting shapes that can be later translated to a particular programming language source code.

I'll be using only the basic shapes of flow-charting since this flowchart to source code translator will be used preferably to aid the learning of a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in a commercial scenario, using a commercial graph drawing library like [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) should be feasible.

With this library you can create your own flowchart editor:

- you can declare and create your own specific shapes and behaviors
- drag and drop, as well as interactive modification and creation of elements is supported
- you can add logic to prevent the user from making certain connections (like connecting the end node to the start node)
- the editor supports automatic snap-lines so that creating a nice diagram is made really easy.
- you can use automatic layout algorithms to rearrange the diagrams and/or the edge routings to get nice flowcharts where the information flow is nicely depicted (going from top to bottom or left to right, e.g.)

Take a look at this [interactive set of demos](http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/index.html) (requires HTML 5 capable browsers) and especially [this one](http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/index.html#Table-Editor). The latter shows the drag and drop feature, the automatic layout using a style that is great for flow-charts and the snapping and some more advanced features like grouping and partition grids.

*Disclaimer*: I work for the company that creates that library. There are [other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/) (although not as powerful in my humble opinion).  I do not represent my employer on SO/SE.

Comment: yFiles is a good choice, but my problem is it is commercial. Do you know any non-commercial or any opensource library for my concern sir?

Comment: @user3273526 See my link for more options. If you require only a few features or simpler features, there are also non-commercial options.

Comment: Well, yFiles looks nice, but GOOD GOLLY is it too expensive for a small company.  $17,000 for a product license.