# Arbor.js multigraph support

Tags: javascript, graph, arbor.js

Is there an easy way to support multigraphs (more than one edge between any two nodes) in arbor.js?

Simply plotting the edges parallell to each other a few pixels a part would be enough, but a more sophisticated solution would surely be better - especially with 4+ edges between two nodes.

Comment: I think it's not possible without rewriting deep parts of the lib, because edges can't be redundant, they get overwritten. I suggest to use cytoscape http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/ or some other lib listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/1916781