# JavaScript graph visualization with paths

Tags: javascript, html, graph-visualization

I am looking for a library for graph visualization on a web page.

I would like to visualize a graph consisting of nodes interconnected by edges.
On this graph i would like to show multiple paths (which traverse multiple nodes).
It has to be possible to have multiple routes share the same edge and to assign different colors to different paths.
The layout of the graph has to be done automatically.

I have seen a lot of libraries for graph visualization but none of them seems to support adding paths.
Is anyone aware of such a library?

Basically, I would like to create something like this: http://bgplay.routeviews.org/bgplay.png

Comment: http://d3js.org/
 can do all kind of things, even if there is not an existing example, you can probably make that chart using this library

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

three such lib i know , you can go with vis.js http://visjs.org/ ,Sigma.js http://sigmajs.org/ ,d3.js  http://d3js.org/

Check for network examples in above. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with juvian's comment above, *d3.js* is super extensible, even if there isn't any graph path or route built-in function. And I bet the same is true for *processing.js*. But, have you tried also [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/)? It is network graph specific and it has a built-in function named [breadthFirstSearch](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/algorithms/eles.breadthFirstSearch), which returns a *path* (which you can style and color). Moreover it has built-in support for multiple edges (incident to the same couple of nodes). I would give it a try and if you find anything interesting please report here! Interesting question.