# web library to create a interactive flowchart

Tags: javascript, interactive, flowchart

i am searching for a library in javascript/html to enable my users to create, update and save basic flowcharts(start, end, task, decision, swimlane, fork and join) and create/edit some custom values of each task for later use in one ERP, similar like [here](http://www.fluig.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/headway-imported-image10.jpg)!

I found RaphaelJS and GoJS, with those libraries can i make this interactive flowchart? I need others sugestions to evaluate.

Comment: google is full of suggestions... do what everyone else does ...search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RaphaelJS deals with SVG shapes and generic functions relating to them. 
It has *no explicit support* for creating/manipulating flowcharts.

- You can use [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/) for flowcharts which
  produces charts in SVG format, but the commercial license is not free
- You can use also use
  [plumbJS](http://www.jsplumb.org/demo/flowchart/dom.html) which is
  open source and pretty well documented. This library also has support
  for a VML fallback if the browser is IE8 or below

Answer (score 2):

If it weren't for the "interactive" part, I would suggest to take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript) and answers.

Since you are mentioning commercial libraries, I assume that this is in a commercial scenario, and thus I believe [this interactive flow-chart demo](https://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/flowchart/index.html) is pretty much exactly what you are looking for. Maybe also [this BPMN editing demo](https://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/bpmn/index.html).

The demos are using the commercial [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) Javascript/HTML5 diagramming library. The library provides (among other features) editing capabilities for flow-chart-like and BPMN diagrams, has robust support for (optionally hierarchical, two-dimensional) swim lanes and of course adding custom data and custom interaction logic is easily supported. The most advanced feature though is the ability to automatically arrange the elements on the screen according to the flow-chart logic:

[image]

*Disclaimer*: I work for the company that creates this library. I do not represent my employer on SO, though.

Comment: Just a warning to anyone else investing time in looking at this, it's extremely pricey. Not suitable for individuals or small startups.