# Drawing library for flowchart drawing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vector, sails.js, draw

I am creating a desktop application using `NodeWebKit`, `sails.js`, and `AngularJS` where users can create documents and add flowcharts, diagrams, etc., similar to [draw.io](http://www.draw.io/) and [Gliffy.com](http://www.gliffy.com), which allows a user to create a flowchart by dragging and dropping from the sidebar.

Are there a JavaScript library which allows me to do that?

Comment: I am actually looking for using d3 to simulate draw.io

Answer (score 2):

[D3.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js) would be a good starting point if you are going to code the functionality yourself. It allows you to manipulate SVG images with the use of data.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason I created [Diagramo](http://diagramo.com). It's open source and it might fit your need.

Comment: I go to the GitHub, and the last update is like 7 years ago already.  And also php is used.

Comment: PHP was used to save whatever you created.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many graph drawing libraries available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript/2366237#2366237).

Even the library that `draw.io` is based on is available commercially.

My personal recommendation would be the yFiles for [HTML JavaScript graph drawing library](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) library, though, which to the best of my knowledge is the most feature complete commercially available library of that kind.

<sub>I work for the company that creates said library, so you may find my opinion biased. I do not represent my employer here on Stack Overflow, though. This is my own opinion.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The underlying library to draw.io is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph).

Comment: Yes, mxGraph is the library I am learning now. Its API is quite large to produce various kinds of nice looking diagrams.