# Tree-like Graph Equation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph

I want to create a graph using HTML/CSS and JS, which should look like this http://prntscr.com/7ky4em and should be able to expand both downwards and upwards. I was wondering, if anyone knows any algorithm for handling this one considering that the width of each element is the same.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript), either to use as-is or as inspiration.