# Looking for a recommendation to visualize dependencies around time axis on the web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, dependencies, visualization

I see there are a lot of questions (and answers) around visualizing dependency graphs [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript) and many look quite cool but there is one feature that I can't find in any of them which is having an axis of time.

My use case is that I have a bunch of project milestone data where:

- Milestone A depends on milestone B
- Milestone B depends on milestone C
- etc

Using any of these graph libraries I could draw those connections but each of these milestones have dates on them so I want to visualize this along a date axis so I can not only see the dependencies but where they line up along time.

Are there any recommendations for any jquery plugin, etc that support this capability?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of dependencies and dates, it sounds like you are looking for a Gantt chart, and/or the logic behind the ordering/layout of a Gantt display. I have successfully implemented [this jQuery one](http://roberto.open-lab.com/2012/08/24/jquery-gantt-editor/) on a project. I think that may be what you are looking for.