# Using draw.io OR build own interactive flow chart

Tags: flowchart, draw.io

Is it possible to use draw.io like the JQuery UI Library where I can integrate it into a web application? If not, what are the best tools available that I can use to create an interactive flow chart similar to draw.io feature for a web application?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript).

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you! I will explore the options given in the answer.