# Suggestion for data visualization library

Tags: javascript, visualization

I'm working on a web application that should visualize large book dataSet in some sort of multidimensional graph.

The visualization should look something like the image in the website http://www.liveplasma.com/artist-Cinderella.html

[image: Click for Image]

What framework produces similar results?

Comment: I think this answer should well cover your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/2964675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 is "de facto" THE library for dataviz in JS, take a look. Although it seems that you are searching for a Data Graph Viz library