# Interactive graph visualization

Tags: graph, neo4j, visualization

I need to develop an interactive graph visualization, which will run againsta a Neo4J engine. It is expected to have rich visualization features like representing edges accoding to certain attributes (eg. visual width depending on attributes like amount).

By 'interactive' I mean that the end user should be able to click on a node in order to expand neighbour nodes and relationships.

I could not find such a graph visualization library so far. Open source would be a plus.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the official guide for graph visualization directly on [the Neo4J website](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/).

Comment: Thanks @MarcoL, we had already checked that before posting this question. From there, it is still not clear to me, how end user interaction -in the terms described in this question- will be achieved.

Comment: Any library in that article should cover your needs. For further tools you can refer to this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/2964675

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need exactly, our [Sandbox](https://interactor.graphileon.com/sandbox/signup.html) may be what you are looking for. Perhaps we cannot offer you all the plusses you may want, but it's a start.

Disclosure : I work for Graphileon

Comment: your website / link seems to be dead

Comment: @AntonioNoack yes, it's a link from > 4 years ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Popoto JS](http://www.popotojs.com/) is a nice open source tool. 
It doesnt offer the specific feature you're asking for, but it is definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is no such open source tool available as of right now, that supports exploring, visualizing and interacting with Neo4j graph.

You could use https://github.com/johnymontana/neovis.js that can visualize data from Neo4j and draw visualizations based of certain attributes and add interactivity to it. There is also https://www.ayalpinkus.nl/shinglejs/ which looks cool.

I am currently doing something similar and look up to payable versions like https://linkurio.us/ or https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/