# Is there a javascript lib to design an IVR diagram with JSON output

Tags: javascript, diagram, ivr

i need a javascript plugin can design an dynamic IVR diagram and in output can get object for pass to server side.

i found [mxgraph](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/) but not for IVR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample IVR app: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/IVRtree.html

Call `diagram.model.toJson()` to save it as JSON-formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why mxGraph would not work for this kind of task. In fact [any reasonable graph drawing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript)  should be able to able to do that.

I know for sure that you can easily implement great looking IVR diagrams (which are mostly just simple trees with a possibly dynamic automatic layout and a custom visualization for the nodes) with [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml). That library has been created specifically to be highly extensible and as such allows for easily adding your own specific visualization for nodes and edges. Also trees and "near-tree" can easily be laid out automatically and you can create a dynamic interactive visualization of such a tree like in [this decision tree demo](http://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/decisiontree/index.html).

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates the latter of the above mentioned libraries, but I do not represent my employer on SO.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries available for IVR diagrams. You can use d3.js, Gojs and JointJs.