# Looking for ReactJS library to create flows/diagrams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowchart

I'm looking for a react component or a javascript library for creating flows/diagrams.

I need to customize and have various types of nodes.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Flow Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985004/react-flow-chart-library)

Comment: I wanted something simpler. Create custom node types and create connections between nodes.

Comment: A good option https://github.com/lmoraobando/lmDiagram/tree/Dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't many *great* flow and diagram libraries out there, and even fewer *focus* on React.

I suggest looking into [a generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/351836) that integrates well with React.

If this is in a commercial context and/or your requirements are non-trivial, be sure to check out [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml), which is the most powerful library available when it comes to sophisticated diagramming. It also comes with many [React-specific diagramming features](https://www.yworks.com/pages/react-graph-component) like the [React Diagram Integration Demo](https://live.yworks.com/demos/toolkit/react/README.html). This allows you to use [all the features](https://live.yworks.com) in a React powered application.

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates the mentioned library. I do not represent my employer on SO, though. This is my very own opinion.</sup>