# How to implement a drag and drop flowchart using angular 10?

Tags: typescript, angular9, flowchart, ngx-graph

I want to drag various flowchart shapes i.e basic shapes like rectangle, square, circle etc as well as flow shapes, connectors and BPMN shapes from left hand side component in angular 10 and drop it to right hand side angular canvas component and connect the dropped nodes/shapes in the right hand side component using connectors like straight line with arrows to draw a meaningful flowchart diagram.Also if I want to drag the shapes or nodes within the right hand side component,the connectors should also be able to move with the connected nodes/shapes.Even I would like to edit or perform any action on the nodes/shapes.I need to do it in angular 10 with html and typescript only but using open source external angular 10 libraries only.Please let me know how can I do it?Please share an example or demo for the same with both html and typescript code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is going to be closed as it does not fit SO. It is way to broad and will result in opinionated answers, only. Find inspiring answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript).