# How to draw this type of diagram in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, editor, diagram, flowchart, dfd

Would you please help me with this diagram? Because I'm stuck on here for the last 2-3 days. but I didn't get any solution.

[[image]]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you have diffculty in understanding the diagram? Do you have difficulty in translating diagram to reactjs components? Do you want to create react.js app for drawing diagram?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript/2366237#2366237). It has many diagramming libraries. Some of them have React integrations out of the box, but all are JS and HTML and should work in the context of React. _yFiles_ specifically has a lot of React examples and can easily deal with a more complex diagram like the one you have. [Here's more about yFiles and React](https://www.yworks.com/pages/react-diagram-component)

Comment: yes @yogski, my query is how to implement this type of diagram in reactJS and which library we need to use for that.