# Diagram with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, drawing, draw, diagram

I want to draw a diagram like below on the web and after drawing I want it to render the json string. I don't know what the idea is or is there any npm pulgin?

[image: Image Showing a diagram]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70060245/edit) your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this related and more general question about graph visualization frameworks for the web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/351836) which has many different options for diagramming libraries.

Some of them work well with Vue.js but the majority has not been created *specifically* for VueJS. However integrating a library with Vuejs should not be a problem, as VueJS can easily be extended with third party UI components.
After all it's just JavaScript and the DOM.

Some of more elaborate solutions from the above answer show examples of [how to embed a diagram editor and renderer Vuejs into your applications](https://www.yworks.com/pages/vue-js-graph-component), but the integration is relatively straight forward, as you can see from [this GitHub example showing how to integrate a graph visualization component with Vuejs](https://github.com/yWorks/yfiles-for-html-demos/blob/master/demos/toolkit/vue3-cli/src/components/DiagramComponent.vue).

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates the library used in the last two links. However I do not represent my employer here on StackOverflow. You can use the same technique shown in the last link with most of the other libraries shown in the first one, too.</sup>