# Create a Diagram of clickable Button with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodes, diagram

I am thinking about building a React component of a Diagram like this[image]

There is a 'remove' button below each node, clicking on it will trigger remove a node.

And there are external buttons below the 'remove' button to fire  custom functions.

I was thinking about using a Library called KonvaJs: https://konvajs.org/ but it does not seem to work on my case.

Any ideas on Libraries that I can use for this?

Comment: Any good JS diagramming library will do - check out the [list here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript/2366237#2366237). To me, what you are creating very much looks like [this tool](https://yworks.com/app-generator).

Comment: oh, thanks alot, I would take a look